# Converting days into years seconds and minutes

Tags: c++

I tired to create a program that converts years to days,hours,minutes,seconds but i get an error while compiling the program. Here is what i have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

 double years,days,hours,minutes,seconds;

 cout<<"Enter year/s : ";
 cin>>years;

 days = years * 365.2425;
 hours = years * 8.765,82;
 minutes = years * 525.949,2;
 seconds = years * 31.556.952;

 cout << "days : " << days <<endl;
 cout << "hours : " << hours <<endl;
 cout << "minutes : " << minutes <<endl;
 cout << "secodns : " << seconds <<endl;

}
```

Error message: 
error: too many decimal points in number

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "*but i get an error while compiling the program*": Please always copy-paste error texts into the question.

Comment: The error means you did something wrong.  If you read it, it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: The decimal point must be an actual point, not a comma. For thousands separator, use `'`.

Comment: put the return statement **inside** the scope of your main function

Comment: @J.Don Regarding your edit: You are not running your program properly then. But that is a completely different question. Please write a new question if you have trouble with that and explain in it in detail how you compile and run your program (e.g. what IDE you use and what you click, etc.). Also use the search function to look for duplicate questions first.

Comment: I have reverted your last edit, since it changed the question and code in a significant manner. Please don't do that. Instead ask a new question as I explained above.

Comment: I am using cpp shell which is an online compiler.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ `.` is the decimal separator and `'` can be used as thousands separator. (This may be different than in your native language, but you must adapt to this for writing C++ code.)

The error is telling you that you cannot have multiple decimal separators (`.`) in a number literal, as you do have in `31.556.952`.

`,` has a completely different meaning in C++. It is the comma operator that evaluates expressions on both of its sides and returns the right-hand result (if the operator is not overloaded.)

So you can fix your code by rewriting the following lines to:

```
 days = years * 365.2425;
 hours = years * 8'765.82;
 minutes = years * 525'949.2;
 seconds = years * 31'556'952;
```

The `'` separators are not required, you can also remove them. (Also note that they are only available since C++14.)

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, you might be mixing up your commas and decimal points in the following lines. Check to make sure those lines are actually what you want.

```
 days = years * 365.2425;
 hours = years * 8.765,82;
 minutes = years * 525.949,2;
 seconds = years * 31.556.952;
```

Change it to:

```
 days = years * 365.2425;
 hours = years * 8765.82;
 minutes = years * 525949.2;
 seconds = years * 31556.952;
```

**If** these numbers are what you want. I assume you were writing the numbers in the European form.

Comment: after i fix this i get this error : Exit code: 0 (normal program termination)

Comment: and the programm doesn't run

Comment: @J.Don Make sure you are returning something in your main function since its of type `int`. Try `return 0;` at the end of the function.

Comment: i did that and still nothing

Comment: @AaronJones `return 0;` is implicit at the end of `main`. It is never required to write that.

Comment: I use cpp.shell

Comment: Listen to @walnut and create a new question since this has more to do with what IDE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Integral literals in the source code don't follow your specific localization. While in your country you may use `,` for separating the decimal part and `.` for the thousand separator, in C++ source code you must use `.` for decimal separation and `'` for thousands separation (introduced in C++14):

```
// correct:
525'949.2
```